# Need help in writing test for logger.isDebugEnabled()

Tags: junit

Following is the update complete code:

```
public Info verify(final String accessTk) throws AuthenticationException {

    final Info accessInfo = readAccessToken(accessTk);

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {

        logger.debug(accessInfo);
    }


    verifyTkExpire(accessInfo);

    return accessInfo;

}
```

I am not aware of the use of logger and thus trying to see a way to test it.

Comment: This does not make any sense to me. What do you need help with?

Comment: When people are not answering your question, and downvoting it; then just putting the same question again **will not help you**. Instead: Spend time in the help center and understand what it takes to write up a good question. Hint: yours is not. At. All. And repeating that doesn't do any good.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend posting the whole method/function for clarity (each method/function should do only one or so things in order to improve test-ability with unit tests); based on what you gave, maybe do something like:

```
/**
* Tests tryDebug
*/
@Test
public void tryDebugTest() {
    logger testLogger= new logger() //or however you would initialize logger
    Info testInfo= new Info(someInfo); //same type as accessInfo
    Info expected= new Info(expectedInfo);  //expected result from debugging the test info
    logger.enableDebug;
    logger.debug(testInfo); //debugs testInfo
    assertEquals(expected, testInfo);
    //if 'Info' is an array use assertArrayEquals(expected, testInfo);
    //if 'Info' is a class, use something like this for each of it's elements: 
    //assertEquals(expected.getVariable, testInfo.getVariable); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Beanz, can you please consider looking the above updated code snippet. I also tried your suggestion, but seems not to be working.